# Get dataproc worker configuration using python client library

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-dataproc

I want to get the worker count and worker configuration of a dataproc cluster using its name through my python code

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [Cloud Dataproc Python client libraries](https://cloud.google.com/dataproc/docs/tutorials/python-library-example) to query the Dataproc API for this information.

Use the [get_cluster](https://googleapis.dev/python/dataproc/latest/gapic/v1/api.html#google.cloud.dataproc_v1.ClusterControllerClient.get_cluster) method to get your cluster by name and projectId. The returned [cluster object](https://googleapis.dev/python/dataproc/latest/gapic/v1/types.html#google.cloud.dataproc_v1.types.Cluster) will have the worker count, the names of the worker nodes, and other configuration information.